# How to provide a type-annotation for `AsRef`?

Tags: rust

The following code shows were the question originates. Since `as_slice()` is deprecated, `as_ref()` is suggested as replacement.

However, when using it in this context, a type annotation is required.

```
let s = "Hi";             // This is a string slice
// warning: use of deprecated item: use std::convert::AsRef<str> instead, #[warn(deprecated)] on by default
assert!(s.replace("Hi", "Ho").as_slice() == "Ho");
// tests/lang.rs:120:35: 120:43 error: type annotations required: cannot resolve `collections::string::String : core::convert::AsRef<_>` [E0283]
// assert!(s.replace("Hi", "Ho").as_ref() == "Ho");
```

**How can I provide such a type-annotation ?**. The only syntax I would find somewhat applicable is `<MyType as AsRef>::as_ref()`, but I don't know how to do that with an instance.

I am using `rustc 1.0.0-nightly (be9bd7c93 2015-04-05) (built 2015-04-05)`.

Comment: By the way: this example is based on an old test of mine which was ported to the latest rustc. Back in the days, as_slice() was still needed. Nowadays, one would just rely on automatic conversions as described by the various answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your precise case of `String` and `&str`, the simplest is to use the [`Index`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Index.html) syntax:

```
let s: String = "foo".to_string();
let slice: &str = &s[..]; // full range index
```

which in your case, would give:

```
let s = "Hi";
assert!(&s.replace("Hi", "Ho")[..] == "Ho");
```

However, for traits methods like `as_ref()`, you can also call them using the syntax:

```
Trait::method(obj); // equivalent to obj.method();
```

Which allow you to set the types parameters like this:

```
Trait::<T>::method(obj);
```

In your case, an alternate syntax would thus be:

```
let s = "Hi";
assert!(AsRef::<str>::as_ref(&s.replace("Hi", "Ho")) == "Ho");
```

Comment: Actually `&s` (i.e., no slicing) is even simpler.

Comment: @delnan Yes indeed, didn't tink about it. But it doesn't always work (if you want to `match` a `String` against a set of `&str` values for examples, like this http://is.gd/VDuUjn )

Comment: Yeah, it has to be in a context where deref coercions apply. Though one can always do `let foo_str: &str = &foo;` and use that.

Answer (score 8):

In this particular case, you don’t need any fanciness at all: `String` is comparable with `&str` (there is a `PartialEq<&str>` implementation on `String`), so you can just compare them directly:

```rust
let s = "Hi";
assert!(s.replace("Hi", "Ho") == "Ho");
// Or, if you prefer:
assert_eq!(s.replace("Hi", "Ho"), "Ho");
```

In real life you will not often need to call `as_ref` for reasons like this.

Comment: It isn't the `Deref` impl/dereferencing, it is `impl<'a> PartialEq<&'a str> for String`: http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html

Comment: @huon-dbaupp: good point. I hadn’t stopped to think about it properly but indeed things like `==` don’t do any autoref/autoderef like that.